# Conway's Game of Life Rules

Tags: javascript, conways-game-of-life

I'm aware this is kind of vague but I've been trying to implement the rules for Conway's Game of Life in JS but the result I get back is a mess (isn't a correct Conway's Game of Life frame). Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my implementation of the rules?

```
      // Update state of selected cell
      if ((neighbours < 2) && (cells[y][x].colour == "black")) {
        // "Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if by underpopulation."
        cells[y][x].colour = "white";
      } else if ((2 <= neighbours <= 3) && (cells[y][x].colour == "black")) {
        // "Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation."
        cells[y][x].colour = "black";
      } else if ((neighbours == 3) && (cells[y][x].colour == "white")) {
        // "Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction."
        cells[y][x].colour = "black";
      } else if ((3 < neighbours) && (cells[y][x].colour == "black")) {
        // "Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overpopulation."
        cells[y][x].colour = "white";
      }
```

Note: I'm using a 2D array (matrix) to store the state of the game and each cell is modeled as a simple object - the only relevant parameter here being its state (stored as colour, live being "black").

Code in context here: https://github.com/HughEvans01/GameOfLife

Comment: It may be worth explaining what "Conway's Game of Life" is to provide context for the question.

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer at all but this is something I did and may help you: https://codepen.io/ArthyFiciel/pen/LBWZrM. Check "CELLS RULES" and Update FN for Conway rule

Comment: javascript is not python, `2 <= neighbours <= 3` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the same grid that you read. You might want to start out by having two grids, the current state and the new state. Iterate over the cells in the current state to calculate the new state, then use the new state for the next iteration and so on.

There's lots of optimizations you can do, but this will give you a correct starting point.

Also, as others noted, the idiom `2 <= neighbours <= 3` won't evaluate the way you think it will in JS

Answer (score 1):

You're calculating the amount of neighbors with the same data that you are mutating. The effect of this is that a cell can change state between dead/alive and then that cell's new data can be used in the "neighbors" calculation of another cell.

Answer (score 1):

You need two copies of the grid to do it properly. When you're calculating the new generation of a cell, you have to use the value of all the neighboring cells from the previous generation. But you're overwriting each cell during the loop, so some of the neighbors will have their new values instead of the old values.

So create two grids, call one `current_cells` and the other `next_cells`. Use `current_cells` when you're calculating what the new color should be, and assign it to `next_cells[x][y].colour`. You should also have an `else` clause that just copies

```
next_cells[x][y].colour = current_cells[x][y].colour;
```

At the end of the loop, swap their roles:

```
[next_cells, current_cells] = [current_cells, next_cells];
```